# How to search for open ports on network?

Tags: tcp, router

I am wondering how I can scan for open ports on all devices that are hooked up to the router. For example: I got 3 computer connected to router. Each computer has something going on on their `localhost:3000`. My aim is to find all of those opened hosts - to get the following results (ip address on local network):

```
10.0.0.5:3000
10.0.0.10:3000
10.0.0.19:3000
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to send a SYN command to the ports and if the other side responds then the port is open: http://www.binarytides.com/python-syn-flood-program-raw-sockets-linux/

Answer (score 1):

If you're under linux you can use nmap command for this task, for Windows I thinks you can install it too but idk about Windows.